# How can I merge two dictionary entries in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I am using the cedict open source Chinese English dictionary in my project. I have put it in an ActiveRecord modeled postgresql database with no relationships to other models.

It shows 2141 duplicate entries when I run `DictionaryEntry.count(:id, :group => :simplified, :having => 'count(id) > 1')`. The simplified characters are the same in these entries, but the definitions are different.

For example, notice that there are two entries for `放之四海而皆准`, but it has two different definitions:

```
irb(main):009:0> DictionaryEntry.find_all_by_simplified("放之四海而皆准")
  DictionaryEntry Load (193.6ms)  SELECT "dictionary_entries".* FROM "dictionary_entries" WHERE "dictionary_entries"."simplified" = '放之四海而皆准'
[
    [0] #<DictionaryEntry:0x007feb8750f9e0> {
                 :id => 42164,
        :traditional => "放之四海而皆准",
         :simplified => "放之四海而皆准",
             :pinyin => "fang4 zhi1 si4 hai3 er2 jie1 zhun3",
         :definition => "appropriate to any place and any time -idiom; universally applicable/a panacea",
         :created_at => Sat, 22 Dec 2012 03:07:44 UTC +00:00,
         :updated_at => Sat, 22 Dec 2012 03:07:44 UTC +00:00
    },
    [1] #<DictionaryEntry:0x007feb8750f378> {
                 :id => 42165,
        :traditional => "放之四海而皆準",
         :simplified => "放之四海而皆准",
             :pinyin => "fang4 zhi1 si4 hai3 er2 jie1 zhun3",
         :definition => "applicable anywhere -idiom",
         :created_at => Sat, 22 Dec 2012 03:07:44 UTC +00:00,
         :updated_at => Sat, 22 Dec 2012 03:07:44 UTC +00:00
    }
]
```

I would like to merge these two entries so that when I run `DictionaryEntry.find_all_by_simplified("放之四海而皆准")` it would return the object with the deleted object's definition added to the end after a `/` like so:

```
[
    [0] #<DictionaryEntry:0x007feb8750f9e0> {
                 :id => 42164,
        :traditional => "放之四海而皆准",
         :simplified => "放之四海而皆准",
             :pinyin => "fang4 zhi1 si4 hai3 er2 jie1 zhun3",
         :definition => "appropriate to any place and any time -idiom; universally applicable/a panacea/applicable anywhere -idiom",
         :created_at => Sat, 22 Dec 2012 03:07:44 UTC +00:00,
         :updated_at => Sat, 22 Dec 2012 03:07:44 UTC +00:00
    }
]
```

(I might also want to merge the pinyin if it happens to be different, not sure yet... hmm... yeah, I might need to do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering the following commands in the rails console seemed to work for me:

```
dups = DictionaryEntry.count(:id, :group => :simplified, :having => 'count(id) > 1')
dups.each do |d|
twins = DictionaryEntry.find_all_by_simplified(d[0])
if twins[0].pinyin == twins[1].pinyin
twins[1].definition = twins[1].definition + "/" + twins[0].definition
twins[1].save
twins[0].destroy
end
end
```

I had to run it a few times.